# Show my app icon infront off contact

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

As in `WhatsApp`, if you click on a name to call, down the list you will find the `WhatsApp` logo in front of the number if you want to txt using `WhatsApp`.
Can we add the `easyPhoneCard` in that list, so the user can directly call using that option without clicking on the prompt to call.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add in your **manifest** some rules.

In that way,  Android will be able to list your application as compatible with a specific action (here is call action)

I think it will be something like

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

(add this in your activity node that will handle operations)

Comment: I have already done it works when we click to call but I also want to show my app icon infront of contact like whatsapp icon show in front of contact whose are already on whatsapp.