# Adding a custom indicator in device contact app

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am developing a chat app like Viber/Whatsapp. I would like to add a custom indicator in the default contact app of the device. This indicator is to show whether the user is online/offline in my application.

While I was researching I could understand that we can programmatically create an account like Google and thereby we can add our app icon in the device contact app ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227274/how-to-add-programmatically-a-custom-account-in-android)). But can we change the icon dynamically?

Kindly help me if anyone knows more about the contact list handling in Android.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to use [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

There is a very simple example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) where you can get all the Contacts

also you have to customize your

> ListView

according to your needs

I think it may not be possible to customize the ui of internal application. you can only use the intent filter to register your app to listen particular intent like share with

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="sms" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    <data android:scheme="mms" />
    <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
</intent-filter>
```

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701017/display-the-app-icon-if-the-contact-is-associated-with-the-application-in-phone) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921617/how-to-show-app-icon-in-android-phone-book-like-whats-app-skype?lq=1) Link if it helps you

This will go in your android manifest.Hope This will help :)

Comment: This online status icon which I mentioned, its not in my app. I would like to add this icon in the device address book so that if the user opens the address book, he/she should be able to know the people who are online in my app.

Comment: But this is not what I need. @Nitin