# Adding a custom field with an icon in contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

Is it possible to add a custom field with an icon, in Contacts in Android. I saw in DATA_15 field, BLOB can be added. But I don't know how. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read carefully ContactsContract.Data documentation

Comment: is it suitable for you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701017/display-the-app-icon-if-the-contact-is-associated-with-the-application-in-phone

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27921895/2781108

Comment: @Hasanaga: I know that adding a sync adapter and account authenticator, I can add my app icon in a contact in the contacts app. But, is there a way to update this icon? Like an online status?

Comment: why do you want a "sync adapter and account authenticator" ?

Comment: @pskink: If I am wrong, please tell me the exact way of achieving this.

Comment: have you read: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html ? just add a row with your custom MIMETYPE

Comment: @pskink: Still I am not able to understand how can I set an icon as a custom field in contacts. Kindly provide me more information.

Comment: get a Cursor for ContactsContract.Datal#CONTENT_URI for one particular RAW_CONTACT_ID and see how data is stored in ContactsContract.Data

Comment: @pskink: What could be the MIMETYPE to add an icon field?
I could see some of the common MIMETYPEs defined by Android in ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds class. But this won't suite my need I guess. Please help.

Comment: you can use any unique MIMETYPE: for example email uses `vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2` you can use `vnd.android.cursor.item/your.package.whatever`

Comment: @pskink I tried same but still facing an issue..I am able to see my app in Accounts Section with an option to sync Contacts but still my app is not showing in Contact detail page..please check- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905223/app-added-in-accounts-with-contact-sync-option-but-not-showing-in-contact-detail

Comment: @pskink I have added code with issue at github- https://github.com/bhuvnesh123/AppContactSyncSamplegithub.com/bhuvnesh123/AppContactSyncSample ..I have also opened bounty on question..thanks